# ASP.Net Core MVC RedirectToAction is appending controller name in front of returnUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a ASP.Net core, MVC 6 application. I have an AppControler as my initial controller and if a user tries to go to an action that has an [Authorize] attribute, I redirect to my AuthController for the login, passing in the returnUrl for the return. Once authenticated, I use ... return RedirectToAction(returnUrl).

In debug, I can see that the returnUrl string is set to /App/Timesheets. However, in the browser address bar, it has an address of http://localhost:49940/Auth/%2FApp%2FTimeSheets. For some reason it is appending the controller name (Auth) in front of the returnUrl.

Here is my Login action in the AuthController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(vm.Username, vm.Password, true, false);

            if (signInResult.Succeeded)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Timesheets", "App");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or password incorrect");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I can manually enter http://localhost:49940/App/Timesheets in the browser address bar and get to the correct view. Also, if I add

```
returnUrl = String.Empty;  //Test Only
```

before the line...

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
```

to cause it to execute the line...

```
return RedirectToAction("Timesheets", "App");
```

The redirection works just fine. So it has something to do with passing in a string variable in the `"/Controller/Action"` format that is the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

When you have a full URL already, you should return a `Redirect`.  Currently you are doing a `RedirectToAction` which will try to redirect to an action under the current controller (Auth).

```
if (signInResult.Succeeded)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Timesheets", "App");
   }
   else
   {
      return Redirect(returnUrl);
   }
}
```

Comment: This should be considered the correct answer. RedirectToAction should be provided with a Controller's Action, not a URL path.

Answer (score 1):

```
var redirect = RedirectToAction();
redirect.ActionName = "YourAction"; // or can use nameof("") like  nameof(YourAction);
redirect.ControllerName= "YourCtrl"; // or can use nameof("") like  nameof(YourCtrl);
return redirect;
```

Comment: The only difference between this and Stephen’s answer from four years ago is that Stephen uses the more compact constructor syntax. What’s the benefit of this approach over Stephen’s?

Comment: Yes, but for asp.net core api not work style Stephen

Answer (score -1):

I guess it just took writing out the problem description for me to see the problem.

I changed...

```
return RedirectToAction(returnUrl);
```

to...

```
return RedirectToAction(WebUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl));
```

and now it is working properly.

:/